# Who could I print all paths into txt file

Tags: java

Team I'm trying to get all the paths from a directory and save all the directorys and files inside a txt file with the date.

Now I get all the directorys and files with file.getAbsolutePath(), but is only writing just a few paths.

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    String yourDesktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\";
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(yourDesktopPath+"the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");

    try {
        for (File file : fList){
            if (file.isFile()){
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                writer.write(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

        }
        writer.flush();
      } finally {
        writer.close();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `java.nio.file.Files` and it will do the recursive looping for you, you can use it like this:

```java
Files.walk(Paths.get("your_path"))
  .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString())
  .forEach(writer::write);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new PrintWriter(yourDesktopPath+"the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");` truncates the file, erasing whatever you previously wrote to it.

You need to *append* to your file.  FileOutputStream has [a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,boolean%29) which allows you to specify it:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
    new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(yourDesktopPath + "the-file-name.txt", true),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```